# I'm giving wrong mat-dialog-ref <DialogRefClass>

Tags: angular

On giving wrong mat dialog ref. on Close this.matDialogRef.Close() it's working. I need to know WHY ?

```
`private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<WrongPopUpComponent>
```

close() {
this.dialogRef.close();
}`

Comment: can you elaborate the problem you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting problem. just for the sake of knowledge, I'm asking.
dialogRef contains the reference of dialogRef I've mentioned i.e wrong component then why it work. Let me explain with an example.
Let A is mat Dialog I'm working on and is opened.
in dialogRef I'm giving reference of B dialog like private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<BPopUpComponent>.
A popup is opened and i have reference of B popup. on this.dialogRef.close() A popup get closed why ? where as dialogRef has reference of B popup then why A get close. it should throws some kind of error that B popup is not popped etc.

Comment: Please share some code, so we can check it